# How can I use a view of my database in a razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following code but I can not auto-fill the options of a select:

**controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult GetPais()
        {    
            using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                var List = ctx.Countries.ToList();
                return PartialView("_optionsPais", List);
            }
        }
```

**modelCountriesList.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace MySite.Models
    {
        public class CountrisList
        {
            public IEnumerable<Countries> Countries { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**MySite.Context.cs**

```
namespace MySite.Models
    {
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyEntities()
            : base("name=MyEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
        ...
        public DbSet<Countries> Countries { get; set; }
        ...
        }
    }
```

**_optionPais.cshtml**

```
@model MySite.Models.CountrisList
@using System.Web.Configuration;
@using System.Globalization;
@using System.Linq;


@foreach (var item in Model.Countries)
{
    <option value="@item.Ide">@item.Descripcion</option>
}
```

I just want to iterate all the rows of my SQL table:

[image: My sql table]

[image: Site.edmx]

I could not find the way to iterate the rows of my table, they could help me.

or Find another type of path like using LINQ directly in the view, thanks

Comment: Your Razor view model is `MySite.Models.Countris` but you are providing `List<Countries>` to it instead.

Comment: where? on my **modelCountriesList.cs**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting an error while trying access the `Countries` property of a `List<Countries>` object in your Razor view.

Instead, instantiate the view model in the controller action and pass it to `PartialView()` since your Razor view defines its model as `MySite.Models.CountrisList`.

```
public ActionResult GetPais()
{    
    using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities())
    {
        var model = new MySite.Models.CountrisList();
        model.Countries = ctx.Countries.ToList();
        return PartialView("_optionsPais", model);
    }
}
```